# iOS cannot play video

Tags: ios

I am attempting to play a simple mp4 file full screen when a view loads. Here is the code:

I am NOT getting a video at all, but I know the viewDidLoad is being called and that there is a view present.

```
//
//  FirstViewController.m
//  WSTR Finale
//
//  Created by Chris Muench on 10/6/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 World Series of Team Roping. All rights reserved.
//

#import "WatchLiveViewController.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface WatchLiveViewController ()

@end

@implementation WatchLiveViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Talkinghead_Media/H264_test1_Talkinghead_mp4_480x360.mp4"];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    moviePlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(moviePlayer.view.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2));
    UIWindow *backgroundWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [moviePlayer.view setFrame:backgroundWindow.frame];
    [backgroundWindow addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer play];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Does it work without the transform? You should probably consider using backgroundWindow.bounds instead of .frame to avoid duplicating offsets.

Comment: I'm sure you are aware of the `frame` and `bounds` properties are undefined (it can be even `CGRectNull`) before you put the actual view controller into the navigation stack – and the `–viewDidLoad` method is invoked definitely _before_.

Comment: I tried to change it to viewDidAppear and now I just get a big black screen without any video controllers or a video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpvController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
mpvController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
mpvController.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
mpvController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(mpvController.view.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2));
[self presentViewController:mpvController animated:NO completion:^{
    [mpvController.moviePlayer play];
}];
```

Comment: Can you make this play in portrait?

Comment: yes, comment out the mpvController.view.transform line

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `prepareToPlay`. Try something like this:

```
...
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: I tried that, but it still didn't play...just an empty view

Comment: I also tried to change it to viewDidAppear and now I just get a big black screen without any video controllers or a video